# What is specific purpose of Instance<T extends Object> in java

Tags: java, java-ee-7

I dont understand what is the purpose of interface `instance.java`  which extend `Iterable` and `Provider` under package of `javax.enterprise.inject` and it's application. I'm using it many time in my code without the knowledge of what it is.

**My knowledge on this is** it make easy and simple to use by having functionalities of `Iterable` and no need to implement all the contract of required interface. but how does one can match the required signature?

This is my simple interface for all the contract require in validating something.

```
public interface GeneralValidator {
   public void validate(String code);
   public void validate(int id);
}
```

When I need this interface, I dont implement it I just simply `@inject` it in my required class and iterate using `for` loop by using

```
@Inject
Instance<GeneralValidator> validators;
```

I cant find it purpose and why it is different, how it work?

Answer (score 2):

From the [`Instance` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html):

> Allows the application to dynamically obtain instances of beans with a specified combination of required type and qualifiers.

Comment: Thanks, I was not able to find javadoc.

Comment: @B'bekShakya Googling the fully-qualified class name (javax.enterprise.inject.Instance) would yield more useful results, since `Instance` is a pretty common name.